# Lua in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, lua

I'm looking at beginning to learn Lua and was wondering if it is possible to edit, run and debug Lua code in Visual Studio 2012 in a C++ environment. I have looked about and found that there are plug-ins for visual studio 2008 and 2010, but currently cannot seem to find any information on what I am looking for.

A good starting point would provide syntax highlighting for Lua code. Integration with the debugger would be nice. The ability to debug seamlessly between Lua code and C or C++ library code would be an ideal.

If not VS2012, then what IDE should be considered?

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio, you are on Windows. In this case, the best way to go is with the [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/downloads/list) package. This will give you a code editor called SciTE with syntax coloring and built-in help for most of the Lua standard library. It will also give you a Lua interpreter and a large mass of usable libraries all built consistently for Windows.

Comment: For a much more complete IDE environment, check out the amazing [Zero Brane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/). It provides a complete IDE with decent debugging support for Lua hosted in a variety of environments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

have found this one: http://techneilogy.blogspot.de/2012/02/compiling-lua-with-visual-studio-2010.html

> Compiling Lua with Visual Studio 2010
>
> Download Lua
>
> 1. Download the desired Lua sources from http://www.lua.org/  At the time of this post, a link to the latest sources can be found at the
>      top of the page:  http://www.lua.org/download.html
> 2. The latest release is compressed in gzip (.gz) format; if you don’t already have something that can decompress this, there are a number of
>      utilities available for free or little charge (personally, I prefer
>      7-Zip).  You can decompress it somewhere as a backup, or else you can
>      decompress it directly after creating a Visual Studio project.
>
> Create a VS2010 C++ Project
>
> 1) Open Visual Studio and create a new Visual C++ project.  The type
>   of project you want to create is the one listed in Visual Studio 2010
>   as File => New => Project… => Visual  C++ => General => Empty Project.
>   Call it whatever you like, e.g. just “Lua” if it won’t conflict with
>   any other version of Lua you’re using, or perhaps “Lua52” if you want
>   to keep track of the version.
>
> 2) Copy or decompress the Lua source files into the default place
>   where Visual Studio puts C++ files.  In VC++ for VS2010 this is in the
>   project folder under the solution folder.  (If you’re unsure, create a
>   temporary .h file and look at where VS has put it.)
>
> 3) Now go back into Visual Studio and add the files into the solution
>   from the Solution Explorer window using the Add => Existing Item…
>   option.  Add all files with a  .h or .hpp extension under “Header
>   Files” and all the files with a .c extension under “Source Files.”
>
> Compile Lua
>
> 1) If you try to compile the project at this point, you’ll get an
>   error message similar to:
>
> luac.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in lua.obj
>
> This is because the Lua distribution includes main files for both the
>   Lua REPL / file interpreter (lua.c) and the byte code compiler
>   (luac.c).
>
> 2) For present purposes, you want the interpreter “lua.c,” so remove
>   the compiler “luac.c” from the project.  Now do a rebuild all.
>
> **Run Lua**
>
> 1) If the rebuild all succeeds, you should be able to run the
>   Lua REPL either inside Visual Studio, from Explorer, or from a command
>   prompt.  The result should look something like this:
>
> 2) Try entering a few lines as a test:
>
> 3) You can also run Lua program files from the command line by
>   following the name of the executable with the Lua program file name.
>   That’s all there is to it.  Now you can begin exploring Lua as a
>   language and as an embeddable interpreter.   No doubt you’ll write a
>   “hello world,” a Fibonacci generator, etc.  If you want to try adding
>   commands to the language itself in C code, you can try creating a
>   function with your name, etc.  And check out the resources available
>   from links on the Lua site, including the “batteries included”
>   versions, and tips for compiling Lua under Windows using other
>   configurations (including links to a few complete projects).

Comment: Isn't the OP after a way of running Lua scripts in VS, rather than building the Lua sources?

Comment: Run Lua is explained as well in the article I mentioned above