# Including Lua in C++ DLL makes it incompatible with C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, lua, pinvoke

I'm trying to make a UI with C# using WPF that calls into an unmanaged C++ .dll.  I've tried using the Platform Invoke method, and also just by compiling the C++ code with the /clr option, which is nicer.  Both of these methods work fine, until the C++ .dll uses any code that includes the standard Lua header files.  To be sure, the C++ code works fine when compiled as an .exe, and also when the .dll is called by another C++ project.

Just for testing, the C# side is something like the first code block below when using PInvoke :

```
namespace ThermoSIM_UI
{
    public class CppInterface
    {
        [DllImport("ThermoSIMDLL_1.2.dll")]
        public static extern int TestPassString();

        public CppInterface()
        {
            TestPassString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the C++ .dll has a header like this :

```
#ifdef THERMOSIMDLL_EXPORTS
#define THERMOSIMDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define THERMOSIMDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

extern "C"
{
    THERMOSIMDLL_API int TestPassString();
}
```

As I say, this works until I have a file in the C++ .dll that uses the Lua includes :

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "luajit.h"
}
```

Ah, and the C# error is this :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'ThermoSIM_UI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
```

Additionally in the Output window there is this :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ThermoSIM_UI.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'ThermoSIM_UI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
The program '[8048] ThermoSIM_UI.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

BadImageFormatException seems to have to do with things like the .dll having a different build configuration, like mixing x64 with x86 or something.  Anyways I haven't figured it out yet.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Has anyone encountered this, or have an idea why this .dll becomes incompatible with C#?

Comment: Are you compiling in "Any CPU"?

Comment: No, I am compiling x64 for the C# and C++

Comment: You just added the .h and stopped working or you use any method from lua?

Comment: Are you building Lua with same config settings as your C++ DLL?

Comment: Just adding the header file includes to a .cpp file and it stops working.  Maybe Schollii's thing is where to look though.  I built the LuaJIT for x64, but it is not through VS like the rest of the projects. http://luajit.org/install.html.  I tried using the prebuilt x64 binaries from here http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html, no luck.  I'm not sure how to build the lua library from VS.

Comment: Following @Schollii's advice did the trick: If I build Lua myself with Visual Studio, it works.  This post helped, with a small modification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302942/lua-in-visual-studio-2012.   1) download Lua files http://www.lua.org/download.html 2) made a new Visual Studio project that creates a library.  I made a static library.  3) remove the interpreter file lua.c because it conflicts with luac.c 4) compile with same settings as my c++ dll, which is x64, Release.  Now the C# project can call into the C++ dll.

Comment: @premes If you could move that last comment into an answer I would upvote it. You can accept it, this way the question gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Schollii's advice did the trick: If I build Lua myself with Visual Studio, it works. This SO post helped, with a small modification: [Lua in visual studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302942/lua-in-visual-studio-2012).

1. download Lua files lua.org/download.html
2. made a new Visual Studio project that creates a library. I made a static library.
3. remove the interpreter file lua.c because it conflicts with luac.c
4. compile with same settings as my c++ dll, which is x64, Release.

Now the C# project can call into the C++ dll.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so it can be closed

Comment: Ah thanks, it won't let me for 10 more hours.  Thanks for the help, I had thought just because I had A x64 version of Lua it would work.  It is a tricky error though because it wasn't so verbose.